# On conditional expectation of tracial C star algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra with a trace $\tau$. $B$ be a C*-subalgebra of $A$. Do always exist trace preserving conditional expectation exist like in von Neumann algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not even removing the need for the conditional expectation to be $\tau$-preserving. If $A$ is nuclear, any sub-$C^\ast$-algebra $B$ in the range of a conditional expectation will also be nuclear. But there are non-nuclear $C^\ast$-algebras that embed into nuclear ones.

Comment: can I put nice structure on c star algebra which is not vN algebra, there is good possibility to have conditional expectation?

Comment: I do not know. One case is when the subalgebra $B$ is given by the fixed elements of an amenable group action.